# Passing multiple variables to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I get error in partial line #1: `undefined local variable or method 'level'`

Code in my view:

```
<div id="comments">
    <% level = 0%>
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <%=render partial: 'comments/single_comment', locals: {level: level, comment: comment} %>
    <% end %>
    <% if 0 < level %>
    <% (level).times do %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And partial first lines:

```
<% if comment.level < level %>
  <% (level - comment.level).times do %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Try inside your partial using `@comment` and `@level` maybe

Comment: Funny thing is `comment` variable in partial works, `level` doesn't. Is this because I set it before the block?

Comment: are u sure `Comment` has a column called `level`?

Comment: yep, 100% sure, just double checked it. But it's not `comment.level` problem but `level` variable.

Comment: try to call `comment.level` in your view. I believe the problem is not related to the variable...

Comment: Looks like it is, I changed `level` to `@level` and left only `locals: {comment: comment}`, in partial I changed local variable `level` to `@level` as well. All works fine this way.

Comment: `comment` works because it yields to the each block.

Comment: Try `..., :locals => {:level => level, :comment => comment}`

Comment: @AlexQueue The new hash syntax is fine. He's just passing the `level` variable as a parameter and needs to reference it accordingly. Namely, `params[:level]`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this code should be work(it's no so good, but it should be work)
I think problem that you use your partial (comments/single_comment) elsewhere in some part of code what we didn't see without 'level local' :)

Comment: Unfortunately not :(, just run grep to double check it.

Comment: can I see "Application Trace" here?)

Answer (score 1):

seems like the code is right .. try to check if you have any partial view that use single_comment filename ... and also you can use collection instead doing a loop

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/single_comment', collections: @comments, locals: { level: level } %>
```

Comment: just run `grep -r 'single_comment' .` in `views` directory and it's the only place I use it (thanks for collections tip)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing arguments to the partial in a wrong way. update it to following.

```
<%=render partial: 'comments/single_comment', locals: => {:level => level, :comment => comment} %>
```

now you can access your objects in partials as follows

```
<% if locals[:level] < level %>
  <% (level - locals[:level]).times do %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```